# How to fetch cpu usage for any instance from compute engine usage report?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am fetching the compute engine usage report from google cloud platform. It is showing several metrics related to instances/disks/networks etc. But it seems it only shows total cpu cores, memory, etc. Nothing specific like CPU Usage percentage, Ram utilization, available disk space. How can we get these data?

I have viewed the daily generated csv file of gcp usage report, it contains measurements like: 
Licensed...Core all showing 172800 seconds(probably telling available cores per day), 
Licensed...CoreRange_1_OrMore all showing 86400 seconds, 
licensed...Ram all showing 695784701952000 byte-seconds, 
storagePdCapacity- varying data in byte-seconds, 
VmimageN1StandardCore- all showing 345600 seconds, 
VmimageN1StandardRam 2412053633433600 in byte-seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gcp usage report shows the resources used in a daily basis for billing purposes, that's why they are displayed in seconds of usage.

If you want to watch the metrics of an specific vm instance, you can do it by going to:

Compute Engine, VM instances, Your_instance_name and click in the "Monitoring" tab.

Nevertheless, this tab does not show RAM usage.

For RAM usage and more specific metrics, you could use stackdriver monitoring, for this you should install the monitoring agent in the desire vm instance, please refer to [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/install-agent), then, create some dashboards  to visualise your metrics, you can find that [here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/charts/).

Also [here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-compute) is documentation about the metrics that can be monitored in stackdriver.

Please consider the pricing for using stackdriver, details [here](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/pricing)

Comment: Can't we download these metrics in "Monitoring" Tab like billing report on daily basis?

Comment: Well, there is not an option for download directly in Cloud Console. But you might be able to use the stackdriver api to get the metrics in json. You can check and do tests here https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.groups.members/list